# OpenID Connect over ADFS

Tags: adfs, openid-connect

I am trying to configure ADFS as an OpenID provider as generic authentication system for multiple application stacks (my objective is to define a solution usable on multiple stacks).

After several tests, we reached a level where we are able to authenticate the users and to retrieve the id_token.

Now, the problem is in the claims we receive in the default id token does not include some of the claims we considered "standard" such as the email one.

We currently use as Claim Provider Trust, our corporate Active Directory.

The list of claims we receive is part of the claims declared as default in the limitations sections of this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/adfs

The claims provided are:

> aud, authenticationinstant, c_hash, exp, iat, iss , name, nameidentifier, nonce, upn, pwd_exp

In our case the upn field matches the email attribute and therefore we have a sort of workaround.

My objective anyway would be to be able to ship the email claim as part of the id token in order to standardize our solution with other OPs currently being in use and do not force applications to change their code base.

How can I configure ADFS to ship the additional claim over the id token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That article is somewhat misleading because Azure AD is in the mix and you have federation.

Also it shows "pwd_exp" which you do not get by default. You have to enable it.

In terms of your question, there is no way to augment the claims because there is no tab where you can enter claims rules.

Refer [Customizing Id_Token Claims with OpenId Connect in AD FS 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/customize-id-token-ad-fs-2016) for a way to get around this using the "Web browser accessing a web application" profile.